# C# create object for same class in the class itself

Tags: c#, .net

I am just trying out some things in c#  and i came across this where i have created an object for the same class in the class itself

```
class Class1
    {
        public int test1 { get; set; }
        Class1 x = new Class1();
    }
```

and then i have tried to create object from an other class which is throwing an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in Test.exe

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 x = new Class1();
        }
    }
```

i have googled and i havent found  any related links to c# but i found it in c++ where they say a Class1  is an incomplete type, as it has not been defined yet, rather it's being defined. I would like to know whether its the same case for c# also

Comment: Just curious why are your creating a `new Class1()` in each instance of your object?

Answer (score 13):

`Class1` creates a `Class1`, which creates another `Class1`, which creates another `Class1`, which ...

So each constructor call gets added to the execution stack until it overflows.

Since you don't specify what you want to *do* with the instance there's no way to know what the right answer is.

For good geek humor, Google [recursion](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion)

Comment: There is no real reason behind that. I have  just tried to see  what happens.

Comment: It works with an interface. See my answer.

Comment: I came across this when I was checking the abstract classes (C# Reference) - [MS doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)

Bottom of the documentation the derived class from the abstract class instantiate a new object inside the Main method.

Is that correct?

Comment: @CodeCanyon I'm not certain what you're referring to or what it has to do with the question. Maybe you should ask a separate question with a specific example?

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty straightforward, your problem is every time you create a `Class1`, that object creates its own `Class1`.  Hence, you're going to recurse until you blow up.

You can debug it and watch what happens.  Set a breakpoint within `Class1` somewhere and watch it get hit over and over.

Answer (score 5):

A class can contain an object of itself, but you can't instantiate that object in constructor or at the time of declaration. This will cause infinite recursion and `StackOverflow` exception.

You can have a separate method to instantiate like:

```
class Class1
{
    public int test1 { get; set; }
    private Class1 x;

    public void CreateClass1()
    {
        x = new Class1();
    }
}
```

and then call it like:

```
Class1 obj = new Class1();
obj.CreateClass1();
```

Comment: Is it good Practice to create like that? When can we write like this? Can you provide an example(real-scenario) if it is valid and good, please?

Comment: The idea about not initiating the nested class makes a difference and is not something mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't create instance of `Class1` during creation of `Class1` instance. Put a placeholder instead:

```
class Class1
{
    public int test1 { get; set; }
    public Class1 AnotherClass1;
}
```

And provide reference to another (already created instance) either after creation or during creation as constructor argument:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Class1 x = new Class1();
    x.AnotherClass1 = new Class1();
}
```